# How return string from protected function php?

Tags: php, function, class, hash, protected

I would like to
pass a string variable and a variable action from the index file to function, I would like the public function to transfer these variables to the protected function
protected function to extract coding depending on the action
and returned the result to the public function and then to the index file
I want to do something like that
but something still does not go away.
could anyone help me with this? Please

index.php

```
$um = new Code;
if($um->Code_x('xxxstringxxx', 'D')) {
echo$_SESSION['output'];
} else {
echo'something wrong';
}
echo $output->Code_x;
```

Code.class.php

```
class Code
{   
    protected $stringx;
    protected $action;

    public function Code_x($STRINGX, $ACTION) 
    { 
        $this->stringx = $STRINGX;
        $this->action = $ACTION; 
        self::Hash_1($STRINGX, $ACTION);    
    }

    protected function Hash_1( $stringx, $action ) 
    {
        $secret_key = 
            'xxxstring_secret_keyxxx'
        ;
        $secret_iv = 
            'xxxstring_secret_ivxxx'
        ;
        $output = false;
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash( 'sha512', $secret_key );
        $iv = substr( hash( 'sha512', $secret_iv ), 64, 16 );
        if( $action == 'E' ) {
            $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $stringx, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv ) );
            return $output;
        }
        else if( $action == 'D' ){
            $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $stringx ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );
            return $output;
        }


    }
}
```

could anyone help me with this? Please

Comment: Is your class named code or code_x?  Your example shows it's named Code but you instantiate Code_x.  If you have a method named the same as the class, it will be used as the constructor.

Comment: class is Code, public function is Code_x

Comment: Well, `echo $output->Code_x` is a way to access a property, not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
self::Hash_1($STRINGX, $ACTION);
```

To this...

```
return $this->Hash_1($STRINGX, $ACTION);
```

And you probably also want to change `$output->Code_x` to `$um->Code_x` as well, since you don't define `$output` anywhere in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

everything works now
I did not realize that even that
the space between the brackets will generate "return false" anyway THANK YOU ALL 
Devon, Coffee'd Up Hacker, Blue